# Pointcloud_to_Laserscan correctly installed?

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I'd like to use the pointcloud_to_laserscan package to downgrade
the PCL-Data, that I get from a Kinect, and use the 2D-Scan for the navigation stack.

Right now, I'm not sure, if I installed pointcloud_to_laserscan correctly.
I have downloaded the files(http://bilibot-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/.../Pointcloud_to_Laserscan) and have run rosmake(no errors).

The auto-fill-in function of rosrun works fine - I can find the package.

Eventhough the "nodes" I could launch are a little awkward - "CloudScan.cfg" and "libcloud_to_scan.so" do not seem correct.

cliffs:
-tried install PCL_to_Laserscan
-rosmake without error
-package found by roscd, rosrun, etc
-nodes seem wrong(*.cfg and *.so)

Edit:
So, the nodes seem fine - how do I run them?!
CloudScan.cfg just creates some reconfiguration files and
with libcloud_to_scan I get some memory error -
guess the translation is segmentation fault.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43080/pointcloud_to_laserscan-correctly-installed?/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "nodes" are OK. rosrun just looks for anything executable, including libraries and the .cfg script.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-09-05**:
thx, still...I get an error(-> see edit above)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-05**:
Well, you shouldn't/can't run those as ROS nodes. The package you linked to actually provides two nodelets, so you'll need to load them as such. Here is an example: http://answers.ros.org/question/9450/how-to-setup-pointcloud_to_laserscan/